# How to create aliases for node repl?

Tags: node.js

In bash and in many language repl's I create an alias for 'x' as exit.
Often in a `~.[thing]rc` file (I am on Ubuntu)

How could I do this in my local node install ?

I tried:

```
$ node
Welcome to Node.js v12.14.1.
Type ".help" for more information.
> const x = process.exit();
$
```

But it actually exits at the same time :(

If I do

```
> const x = process.exit;
```

Then I can do `x()` to exit - which is pretty close - but not quite as simple as plain `x`.

Also I have to set this up manually each time I use the `node` repl, which will not work - How can I have a setup that works every time I use the node repl automatically.

btw I can also use `.exit` and ctrl-c as alternatives

Comment: You can create `.` commands, which is also not what you want. Perhaps getters with the functionality you want on the context?

Comment: `.x` would be a step closer. how to do that?

Comment: Depends; just from `node` you might not be able to--I almost never do just that, rather I have a thin wrapper that starts up a repl so I can shove project- or context-dependent stuff into it. Docs for that are on the NodeJS Repl page and there are a few things around the webs