# How to create an 'x' command to exit node

Tags: node.js, alias

In bash and in other language repls (`irb` for example) I add some form of `alias x='exit'`

This gives an easy and comfortable two key <kbd>x</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> way to exit with no finger stretching, shift, ctrl, etc.

When I am in a shell and then in a repl and quick <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> ends that terminal window session.
I don't just 'close window' in case I have unsaved work or WIP.

How can I get <kbd>x</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to do that in node either through an alias or some other way, like custom command perhaps? Currently I have to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create aliases for node repl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59756203/how-to-create-aliases-for-node-repl)

Answer (score 0):

A better approach might be to remap <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> so you can hit <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> without moving from home row, without stretching, and while getting the same benefit for all Ctrl+ shortcuts on the system without configuring anything per-application.

Anyways...

Create a file `x.js` containing:

```
Object.defineProperty(global, 'x', { get: process.exit });
require("repl").start();
```

Now when you run `node x.js`, you get the behavior you want:

```
$ node x.js
> Math.random()
0.4278784631149126
> x
$
```

Note that anything that accesses the global variable `x` will similarly cause the process to terminate.